# Executing 2 or more Runnables causes performance issues

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, runnable

I need to factor a 64-bit number (n = pq).
So I implemented a method which searches consequentially all numbers in range of [1; sqrt(n)].

It took a 27 secs to execute on Android with 1,2 GHz processor (unfortunately, I don't know a number of CPU cores). So I decided to make it parallel. Well, two `Runnables` giving me results in 51 secs and 3 — in 83.

My program does nothing but calling this method in `onCreate`.

```java
final static private int WORKERS_COUNT = 3;

final static public int[] pqFactor(final long pq) {
    stopFactorFlag = false;

    long blockSize = (long)Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(pq) / WORKERS_COUNT);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(WORKERS_COUNT);

    for (int workerIdx = 0; workerIdx < WORKERS_COUNT; ++workerIdx) {
        Runnable worker = new FactorTask(pq, workerIdx * blockSize, (workerIdx + 1) * blockSize);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}


private static boolean stopFactorFlag;
private static int p, q;

static private class FactorTask implements Runnable {
    final private long pq;
    private long leftBorder;
    private long rightBorder;
    public long pInternal;
    public long qInternal;

    /* Constructor was there */

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (qInternal = rightBorder; !stopFactorFlag && qInternal > leftBorder && qInternal > 1L; qInternal -= 2L) {
            if (pq % qInternal == 0L) {
                pInternal = pq / qInternal;
                p = (int)pInternal;
                q = (int)qInternal;
                stopFactorFlag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P. S. This is not a homework, I really need this. Maybe the other way.

Comment: The conditional in your `for` loop gets way nastier when you multi-thread the problem.  `x -= 2L` is WAY slower than `x--` after optimization, and the additional stopping flag also adds overhead.  Those may be part of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Executing 2 or more Runnables causes performance issues

This looks to me that your Android device has either 1 or 2 cores and that adding threads to your problem is *not* going to make it run faster because you have exhausted your CPU resources.  I'd recommend looking up your device specs to determine how many cores it has.

If I run your code under my 4 core MacBook Pro:

- 2 threads in ~6secs
- 3 threads in ~4secs
- 4 threads in ~3.5secs

This seems to me to be reasonably linear (taking into account startup/shutdown overhead) and indicates to me that it is not the code that is holding you back.

Btw, the `stopFactorFlag` should be `volatile`.  Also I don't see how you are creating your `result` array but I'm worried about the race conditions there.

Comment: Result array is created after `try..catch` block so no race conditions there. So since I don't know specs of this device (no-name chinese tablet, programs don't show me nothing but CPU speed) I assume it is a single-core. I had a hope that the issue is in my code, but now I would rather copy someone else's Rho-Pollard algorithm.